# Scale down iPad Pro App to iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad, screen, resolution

I am going to build a new app for iPad Pro (its my main target device), Also i want the iPad Air users be able to run the app as down scaled version.

I can use autolayout to support both the devices, but my design has certain constraints that by using autolayout i can't achieve the exact design.

I want some thing like scaling down from iPad to iPad mini which is done by apple.

Is it possible to scale down using any explicit setup?

Comment: Just a kind recommendation, your app would look terrible downscaled, so highly consider redesigning the app. As far as the iPad and iPad mini are concerned, the app scale is the same but the physical pixel density is larger so it appears smaller. If you really want to ignore this and carry on, use whateverView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x, y)